# How to get followers count from twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want the followers count from twitter site , Already I used this query, its worked well, but its not worked now,because the twitter API was changed now.i used script for getting count in a span `id ="spnTwitterFolowersCount"`.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("https://twitter.com/users/Obama.json?callback=?",

    function (data) {
        document.getElementById("spnTwitterFolowersCount").innerHTML = data.followers_count;
        //alert('Obama has ' + data.followers_count + ' Followers');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As the followers count is accessible from anybody on a twitter profile you can use YQL:

```
var ttid = "twitterUsername";
var response = $.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20content%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2F"+ttid+"%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fli%5Bcontains(%40class%2C%22ProfileNav-item--followers%22)%5D%2Fa%2Fspan%5Bcontains(%40class%2C%22ProfileNav-value%22)%5D'&format=json&callback=");
return response.success(function (followers) {
    return followers;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot has changed with the twitter API 1.1, for first, you cannot makes call directly to get data. You need to have some sort of authentication for making those calls.

Please read this [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Authentication_required_on_all_endpoints) which states the need for authentication. You can have [Oauth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth) authentication or [app-only](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) authtentication based on your needs.

After you are done with the authentication, you can get the list of followers using this api

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=sitestreams&count=5000
```

[Read here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids) for more information and complete set of parameters