# How to get the Twitter followers count using Twitter API (in 2022)?

Tags: api, twitter, count

I am surprised to see that there is no way to simply get the number of followers for one Twitter account.

I found many answers ([Follower count number in Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409227/follower-count-number-in-twitter), [How to obtain follower count in Twitter API 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974764/how-to-obtain-follower-count-in-twitter-api-1-1), [How to get followers count from twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526709/how-to-get-followers-count-from-twitter), [Twitter follower count number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683228/twitter-follower-count-number)) which are way too old as they either use services that do not exist anymore, or make use of the Twitter API v1.1 (instead of the current v2 API).

I found an interesting way (but unsupported) to get the number of followers, using the code of their follow button.

```
https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?screen_names=elonmusk
```

However, I am looking for an official way to retrieve this what I think a simple data from Twitter.

Also note that the official Twitter v2 API does not allow to fetch a count but only **to list the followers page per page**, which is far from what I try to achieve.

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/44196397/followers
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way to do this using the Twitter API v2!

The follower and following counts for a user are part of the `public_metrics` fields in the User object.

The API endpoint and parameters are in the format

`https://api.twitter.com/2/users/[ID]?user.fields=public_metrics,[any other fields]`

Here's an example of the output, using the `twurl` command line tool (which handles the authentication etc, you may need to use a library to help with OAuth):

```
$ twurl -j "/2/users/786491?user.fields=public_metrics,created_at"
{
  "data": {
    "id": "786491",
    "username": "andypiper",
    "created_at": "2007-02-21T15:14:48.000Z",
    "name": "andypiper.xyz",
    "public_metrics": {
      "followers_count": 16570,
      "following_count": 3247,
      "tweet_count": 134651,
      "listed_count": 826
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I completely passed near the additional user fields. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user
Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to get followers count by user name? Or additional request to fetch user Id by user name is needed?

Comment: @moonvader Yes, you can use the twitter username: `https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/TwitterDev?user.fields=public_metrics`

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to get followers count not by user id but using user name

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/{username}?user.fields=public_metrics
```

Also you will need to create app in Twitter Developer Portal, receive auth token and use it in your request's authorization header

```
Authorization: Bearer {token}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the followers list for a specific Twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script