# How to obtain twitter follow count history

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

I want an API, or a way to obtain the Twitter follower count, of several twitter counts, for example, Twitter follower count of several Twitter accounts, from 1st September 2021 to today(9th February 2022),whether paid or not, if anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you asking someone to make it for you or are you asking how it can be done?

Comment: i am asking for the api, if I get it, I would do it myself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70779246/how-to-get-the-twitter-followers-count-using-twitter-api-in-2022

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay, the [Social Blade API](https://socialblade.com/business-api) could be worth looking into. Social Blade has historical Twitter stats stored; you can search their website to see if the accounts that you're looking for are there. You could also scrape their website in Python with methods like [this](https://oxylabs.io/blog/python-web-scraping).